# Can you control whether a variable's type is dynamic or static in VB9?

Tags: vb.net, types, syntax

I would like to use VB9 but am not sure what syntax to use to say that I want a variable to be statically typed as in C#'s:

```
var foo = new Whatever();
```

In previous versions of VB:

```
Dim foo = New Whatever()
```

created a dynamically typed variable.

Is there a way to get static typing without actually writing the type in VB9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can control this behaviour through the `Option` directives at the beginning of each file or in the project settings:

```
Option Strict Off

' The following is dynamically typed: '
Dim x = "Hello"
```

---

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

' This is statically typed: '
Dim x = "Hello"
```

It's best-practice to set `Option Strict On` as the default for *all* your projects (can be done in the options dialog). This guarantees the same typing behaviour as in C#. Then, if you need dynamic typing, you can disable the setting selectively on a per-file basis by using the directive mentioned above.

Comment: Ahh, too bad it's on a per-file basis. I wish I could do it on a per-variable basis.

Comment: "Option Infer On" just allows the practice... you can still dim X as Object or Dim X As Integer